# php sed like functionality

Tags: php, regex, sed, equivalent

I am quite familiar with sed on bash shell, so I do

```
cat $myfile | egrep $pattern | sed -e 's/$pattern/$replace/g'
```

a lot. Quite a few times, I find that I need to do similar kind of "string parsing" inside PHP.

So my question is simple, what is the equivalent of `sed -e 's/$pattern/$replace/g'` in PHP ?

I know preg_match , preg_replace , but I haven't used them / not at all familiar with them. I would really appreciate sample code in PHP. (converting say a `$var = '_myString'` to `$newVar = 'getMyString'` )

Comment: There is also str_replace() - when you don't need more advanced regexp.

Comment: thanks @EO2 : I didn't think about str_replace() ! , will certainly try and avoid regex whenever I can with str_replace() .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `preg_` functions uses the same regexp library that Perl does, so you should be at home. There's documentation of the syntax [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php).

For example:

```
sed -e 's/$pattern/$replace/g'
```

Would be something like:

```
$output = preg_replace("/".$pattern."/", $replace, $input);
```

The most common is to use `/` as delimiter, but you can use other characters, which can be useful if the pattern contains lots of slashes, as is the case with urls and xml tags. You may also find [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) useful.

Comment: thanks, I am going through preg_* PHP manual pages, and preg_quote seems a handy function. Can you point/explain the 'e' flag for PCRE ? And how to use it ? (I guess its there somewhere in the PHP manuals ...)

Comment: I've never used the `e` modifier - I prefer using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), which semantically does the same thing.

Comment: thanks, I will go through it, sounds much cleaner and simpler (writing a regex itself is a complex task, no need to add extra burden of `e` modifier)

Comment: Remember that newer versions of php (5.3+) have support for anonymous functions, which are perfect for this case.

Comment: yes, I know, aren't they called closures ? Or maybe I am wrong, as I faintly remember that Anonymous Functions and Closures are not exactly same. Thanks again.

Comment: It's sort of the same thing, yes. A closure is the runtime binding of an anonymous function along with a capture of the stack. Think of an anonymous function as a class and a closure as an object. It's not exactly right, but close.